# Java: How to use synchronized and volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

I have two threads. The first thread calls the setX method, the second one calls the getX method. Do I have to set the methods synchronized although i have only one writing thread? And can i also solve my thread problem with the second class and the volatile variable?

```
public class Test {
    private int x;  

    public synchronized  void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public synchronized  int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
}

public class Test2 {
    private volatile int x; 

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Rather than use `synchronized` *or* `volatile` here, I'd personally use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html):

```
public class Test {
    private final AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger();  

    public void setX(int value) {
        x.set(value);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x.get();
    }
}
```

(Note that I've also fixed your `get` / `set` - previously your `getX` was setting, and your `setX` was getting...)

Comment: But the class with volatile is also a solution?

Comment: @user1720132: I believe so, but it's less clear - you need to learn about the Java memory model in detail to reason about it. Using `AtomicReference`, it's obvious exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is implementation independent, hence preferable.

Comment: volatile and synchronized are also implementation independent. I agree an AtomicInteger is the clearest solution though.

Comment: regarding get()/set(), Test2 looks identical to AtomicInteger, which is backed by a private volatile int, too.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, you need some form of synchronization. Since your shared state is a single variable, and this variable is of type `int`, a write will be atomic (it would not be the case if the variable was a long or a double). But you still need synchronization to make sure that you have no *visibility* problem: thread A could write to the variable, and thread B could not see the written value, but a previous one.

The synchronization can be implemented using synchronized, volatile, or an AtomicInteger in this case. All these techniques will ensure that the write will be visible to any subsequent read of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

> `Volatile` variable only guarantees the visibility of variable and order
>   of codes to the Threads. But it doesnot provide threads the facility
>   of ownership on method. `Synchronized` keyword let the threads to have
>   ownership on the `synchronized` methods.

Going by your Query:

> The first thread calls the `setX` method, the second one calls the `getX`
>   method.Do I have to set the methods `synchronized` although i have only one writing thread?

Depending upon what you want. If you want that Thread2 call `getX` only after Thread1 calls `setX` then yes you need to synchronize the methods but then you would have to use `wait()` and `notify()` methods also.

> can i also solve my thread problem with the second class and the
>   `volatile` variable?

Again , it depends upon what you want. If you wish your Thread2 to call `getX` method without concerning about `setX` method called by other `Thread` then you should use `volatile` so that Thread2 could get up to date value of `x` .